# behavior of chaincode during runtime

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

Currently learning a bit about chaincode development using GO (recently worked with ethereum). I have the following code:

```
type Person struct {
    name string // assume json fields for marshaling etc.
    lastname string // ...
    SSN string //  ...
}

func (p *Person) Init(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) Response {
    args := stub.GetArgs()
    var person Person
    // just assume that args[0] is a json
    json.Unmarshal(args[0], person )
    p.name = person.name
    p.lastname = person.lastname
    p.SSN = person.SSN

}
 ......
```

During the init function I pass a person on the initialization of the chaincode. My question then is: upon another call against the chaincode. Will the p instance still be persisted from the init function such that I can read p.name given during the init? How does chaincode manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find it appears to be persisted if you try it, but it will only be persisted in memory. If the chaincode restarts, or if the peer restarts, then the data will be lost. So this is not a recommended approach.

Chaincode has access to various stores - the world state (similar to the world state in Ethereum) and private data collections. Data stored in the world state is shared across all members of the channel.

You can put data into the world state using `stub.PutState(key, value)`, and get data back from the world state using `stub.GetState(key)`. Your `Init` function should store the data in the world state, and then your `Invoke` function can get the data out of the world state when any transactions are processed.

I recommend you check out the FabCar sample if you haven't already: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/chaincode/fabcar/go/fabcar.go

The `initLedger` transaction adds 10 cars to the world state. The `queryCar` transaction reads a car from the world state. There are other transactions for querying all of the cars, or updating a cars owner.